# Listen on a UDP socket while also receiving input from stdin with C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, udpclient, fgetc

So I'm trying to make a program in C that can receive packets from another computer via UDP, while also being able to stop listening when someone enters "quit" in the command line. My issue is that both fgets and recvfrom wait until something has happened to move on, so if I'm currently executing fgets my program will ignore incoming messages, and if I'm currently waiting for a message it will ignore input to the terminal. Is there any way I can do both of these at the same time?

Relevant Code:

```
while (strcmp(sendline, "quit")!=0) {

    fgets(sendline,MAXLINE,stdin);

    if((nbytes=recvfrom(sd,recvline,1+strlen(sendline),0,
        (struct sockaddr*)&sad, &fromlen))<0){
      perror("recvfrom");
      exit(1);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you consider 2 threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to using low-level IO (read from fd 0 instead of fread from stdin) you can then use the select() function to be notified of when data is ready on either the fd or socket.

Comment: Note, this may somewhat sacrifice compatibility. (You might not be able to `read` or `write` a socket, or `select` a file descriptor. Especially in Windows.)

Comment: On windows it would then be an even lower level of IO (HANDLE instead of file descriptor, although it's easy enough to generate an fd from the right HANDLE types - including both file and console input handles) and select would then work on both. The real problem on windows is that there is just about always a better option than select().

Comment: So I tried using poll instead of select, because from what I can tell it is just a better version of select. However, I am having trouble read()ing the socket. I am using Linux. Would HANDLE fix this issue?